# How to add list valu in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

How to add list values in django choice field?

My code is

```
from django import forms
import os
drives_a = [chr(x) + "," for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    drives = forms.CharField(label='Drive Name', widget=forms.Select(choices=drives_a))
```

Answer (score 0):

choices are normally laid out

```
choices = (
    (key1, 'opt1'),
    (key2, 'opt2'),
)
```

Make sure that works then amend your `drive_a` statement to create it

Comment: can you tell me in details &

Answer (score 0):

## How to add name in drive value in label name

from django import forms
import os,string
from django.forms.models import ModelForm

drives_a = [chr(x)+':'  for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]

## drives_b = (chr(x)+':'  for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':'))

CHOICES_DRIVE = [
    ("Drive", drives_a),

]

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    drive = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES_DRIVE))